# Does the LG V20 use a modified Android OS, or is it stock Android OS?

Tags: lg

I am looking at buying a new phone, and I would like to make sure that the OS that comes with it doesn't have an OEM modifications. I like stock android.

Does the LG V20 use a modified Android OS, or is it stock Android OS?

Comment: Depending on how you define "stock" - and LG phones are always quite far from any of the definitions - you pretty much have no choice.

Comment: Stock android is very much similar to pixel/nexus devices. LG uses customized UI designs than stock android.